# Not able to install Python with OpenCV on windows x64 system

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, opencv3.0

I am trying to install python on my system but facing some issues.

I have installed OpenCV 3.0.0  for Windows x64 bit system and now i am trying to install python 2.7.5 on my system and i also have installed numpy 1.7.1.

Then i copied 'cv2.pyd' from my OpenCV folder to python folder, now in order to configure them i have to import cv2 file but this error is coming when i try that.

[image]

can anyone help me in this i am new in this. Shall i try to work with latest version of python and numpy for my windows x64 system?

Thanks

Comment: Your numpy version is not up to date but not the issue, how did you install opencv? Also where did you copy it to exactly?

Comment: i copied numpy to this location "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research and struggle i found out what the issue was.

My system is Windows x64 bit but this python and numpy most of the times don't work well with Windows x64 bit systems.

So i first i configured my OpenCV as x86, though my system is x64 bit. After that i download 32 bit python and numpy and configured the same with OpenCV and it worked very well.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete way of installing OpenCV with Python

1. Download:
   Python-2.7.11 from https://www.python.org/downloads
   numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.0/
   matplotlib-1.3.0.win32-py2.7.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.0/
2. Install Python-2.7.11
3. Copy the .exe of numpy, matplotlib and opencv and paste them in C:\Python27
4. Run numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
5. Run matplotlib-1.3.0.win32-py2.7.exe
6. In Python Idle, execute import numpy to ensure that numpy is correctly installed.
7. Run opencv-3.1.0.exe
8. Goto opencv/build/python/2.7/x86 folder. Copy cv2.pyd to C:/Python27/lib/site-packeges.
9. copy ffmpeg zip folder to C:\
10. Extract ffmpeg in C:\ffmpeg
11. Copy extracted ffmpeg folder to C:\Python27
12. Locate opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll and opencv_ffmpeg310.dll and copy these at C:\Python27
    (Most likely opencv_ffmpeg310.dll is more important than opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll but not sure. So copy both.)
13. Go to system Variables and set path C:\Python27; C:\Python27\ffmpeg\bin

Comment: Make sure to *add* path `C:\Python27; C:\Python27\ffmpeg\bin` to the system variables, not to replace it!